# I'm going to develop a simple account handling mobile app using React Native, for that what database should i use?

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, react-native, deployment

I'm going to develop a RN app for account management with few tables, not complex. What database should i use for that SQLite / Firebase / any other? I mean it's a simple app and I don't have any prior deployment knowledge.

I have only worked with Firebase. DO we need servers to deploy DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have to deploy database to a server. You can use Firebase as you have already worked with it. Other than that, if you use some other database, you will need to make a backend for this as well.